# Usar atributos do elemento em função no escopo do controller

Tags: html, angularjs

Eu tenho um form que chama uma função ao ser submetido através do atributo, por exemplo:

```
ng-submit="submit('POST', 'example.com')"
```

Gostaria que, nesse atributo, fosse apenas chamado a função, e, na função esses dados fossem pegos através dos outros atributos, por exemplo:

```
<form action="example.com" method="POST" ng-submit="submit()">
    <! ... >
</form>
```

---

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    let action = this.action;
    let method = this.method;
    // ...
}
```

Porém usando apenas o `this` não funciona. Já dei uma olhada no [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), porém achei ele bem mais trabalhoso e não vale muito apena, gostaria algo mais simples, que deixe o HTML limpo sem sujar muito o JS, separando as variáveis que vou utilizar em dois atributos diferentes, caso eu precise altera-los dinâmicamente. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passe como parâmetro no método a expressão [`$event`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

```
<form ng-submit="submit($event)" action="http://example.com" method="POST">
```

depois basta acessar a propriedade `srcElement` da expressão [`$event`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-):

```
$scope.submit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Previne o envio do form
  console.log(e.srcElement.action);
  console.log(e.srcElement.method);
}
```

#### Veja funcionando

```js
angular.module('PTstackoverflow', [])
  .controller('301786', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.clear();
      console.log(e.srcElement.action);
      console.log(e.srcElement.method);
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<form ng-submit="submit($event)" action="//example.com" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Coloquei também no [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/ziyowirihu/edit?console,output) caso o snippet não funcionar aqui.

### Referência

- [`$event`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)